# Tensorflow Probability Regression Setup

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build upon case 2 in https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Probabilistic_Layers_Regression

Say I have a dataframe, I want set up a model like:

Y ~ NegativeBinomial(a,b),

where:

a ~ kerasNN(X), b ~ kerasNN(X)

in much the same way they've done for the Normal distribution in case 2.

However when I do this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1 + 1),
  tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
      lambda t: tfd.NegativeBinomial(
          total_count=t[..., :1],
          probs=1e-3 + tf.math.softplus(0.01 * t[...,1:])
      )
  ),
])
```

I get loss: nan.

Does anyone have a template for this sort of problem or know any accessible reading material for setting this up correctly?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you try

1. parameterizing with logits instead of probs, dropping the 1e-3 offset and softplus constraint
2. set `allow_nan_stats=False`
3. set `validate_args=True`

when constructing your NegativeBinomial?

(1) is because you shouldn't need to constrain logits at all -- it'll be mapped correctly to a probability internally. In fact, when you parameterize with probs, it turns around and converts to logits so this just adds work. Moreover, while softplus is appropriate for the Normal scale parameter in the source example, probs should be between 0 and 1, not just positive. Anyway, use logits and it should just do the right thing.

If (1) works, (2) and (3) are unnecessary, but if you ever encounter bad values with a Distribution, your first instinct should be to set these debugging flags.